# Apache Echarts - custom toolbox feature not showing

Tags: javascript, echarts

In Apache Echarts I want to add a custom button to the toolbox. According to the examples and documentation it must be done in this way. But nothing shows up.

```
  toolbox: {
  right: '20%', 
  feature: {
      dataZoom: {},
      saveAsImage: {},
      magicType: {},
      myCustBut:{
        show: true,
        title: 'test option',
        icon: 'path://"../images/Europa.png"', // tried different options here
        onclick: function() {alert("Test")}
      }
  }
},
```

This is what I see:
[image: This is my result]

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the `icon` property needs to contain a valid input for anything to show up.

The [documentation](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#toolbox.feature.saveAsImage.icon) states that valid inputs are either an image url (not a lokal path) prefixed with `image://`  or an [svg path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths) prefixed with `path://`.

[Example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-simple&code=PYBwLglsB2AEC8sDeAoWszGAGwEbAA8AuZNdWAJwgHMALMEgcgCYAGAUkYBoz0AzAKYBDMAFcKAkqnLkAzkIBuAgIKyAkgFsh1ScgC-PGeg0BPAMKjZYAEKiwARim8jkMNl2MwAq7FCQYsPbczjIQAMYwTBBaOkQA9HH0YCCy8XECYbRCFGCyAHRCIEKZAnnAFNTp0HHR2t5xfIrhMHkg0NTBRuQwYdjhANYkfKLQYf5wABQAlKRdMkLuOROMACreYIGMUwDcIeR6ewZ7phZWtmDMTnMYEG4eXj5-UHDMnXPN0ExFYLRpALIAFgAzMw8gCAKxccEATnBYIBALCrC4oPsAHY0QBaAF5ABsuPsXFxeQAHMxMfZ7HkgaxIcSyWFMcSAWjIawKVSabjsXlwbisZTqaxufTmLIcSTweT6fZmFxBVymaTZWYAcw0aSAYTwSSSXiQVxgaCIXKYUC8vZoYSjWDITC4QiAQAZG0QqGw-EAgBesEBzCp9nBdpJ0NJaNxjPNrFY0K47IdAJJKLBsMxCaTcPBaLFxqBscz2ah8IzvOzYSjhORCehmONsKLCJrBeYquYxNxrAB7tBQLR1uYOPsuODoZJ4cN_otQahIbDuJdk8DI7nPr9AYBuPdVJD9kZVKtm_Z5pZ8t5Icxx7RXHN4IB0KRp9hsapQa7N8T17BV_fJNkx9xNYviGn4bjWP6tjiBJdmaX6xmqUa4qaVqklaE7rpuMLblaC7oVuKH2F6a4WhueE7m8XQ9H0YSDLAwyjOMsDTLM1ywAsAhLKs6ywK8Ox7OgBxdAJ-xkEc6AEMoBAQKkzHoGAJggB4YQiAI1DlCY5GwAAJiIQgkAA2owfwwNwsCrKIAgmYwADqAiaZZKy0KIlkAGJUJZADKIgeSMjAALoiYYsAmBJUlXOQckKUwCgLOZjABWQsjsRA3j6c40hGNpYC6bAemBsi3E0lw3EDkV_pJoEQKQoEJ7cR2vmBTIEUeH00AWc4Qn-Xo2xAA):

```js
option = {
  toolbox: {
    right: '20%',
    feature: {
      saveAsImage: {},
      myCustBut1: {
        title: 'test option 1',
        icon: 'image://https://echarts.apache.org/en/images/favicon.png',
        onclick: function () {
          alert('Test 1');
        }
      },
      myCustBut2: {
        title: 'test option 2',
        icon: 'path://M432.45,595.444c0,2.177-4.661,6.82-11.305,6.82c-6.475,0-11.306-4.567-11.306-6.82s4.852-6.812,11.306-6.812C427.841,588.632,432.452,593.191,432.45,595.444L432.45,595.444z M421.155,589.876c-3.009,0-5.448,2.495-5.448,5.572s2.439,5.572,5.448,5.572c3.01,0,5.449-2.495,5.449-5.572C426.604,592.371,424.165,589.876,421.155,589.876L421.155,589.876z M421.146,591.891c-1.916,0-3.47,1.589-3.47,3.549c0,1.959,1.554,3.548,3.47,3.548s3.469-1.589,3.469-3.548C424.614,593.479,423.062,591.891,421.146,591.891L421.146,591.891zM421.146,591.891',
        onclick: function () {
          alert('Test 2');
        }
      }
    }
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'value'
  },
  series: [
    {
      data: [150, 230, 224, 218, 135, 147, 260],
      type: 'line'
    }
  ]
};
```

Comment: Indeed, this did the trick: icon: 'image://../images/farm.png', Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The icon property was wrong. In my case this had to be:

```
icon: 'image://../images/farm.png',
```

That did the trick.